# Can not use spring actuators - Error creating bean CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Recently I have added dependency for `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator`  because I want to monitor my app status like **UP** etc. but on application startup I am getting this exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache.getStatistics()Lnet/sf/ehcache/statistics/StatisticsGateway;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:137) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at cz.fischer.upe.architecture.core.core.startup.SpringApplicationRun.run(SpringApplicationRun.java:25) [classes/:?]
    at ckf.upe.KtTigerApplication.main(KtTigerApplication.java:37) [classes/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache.getStatistics()Lnet/sf/ehcache/statistics/StatisticsGateway;
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.cache.EhCache2Metrics.<init>(EhCache2Metrics.java:36) ~[micrometer-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.cache.EhCache2CacheMeterBinderProvider.getMeterBinder(EhCache2CacheMeterBinderProvider.java:36) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.cache.EhCache2CacheMeterBinderProvider.getMeterBinder(EhCache2CacheMeterBinderProvider.java:31) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsRegistrar.lambda$getMeterBinder$0(CacheMetricsRegistrar.java:76) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.util.LambdaSafe$Callbacks.lambda$null$3(LambdaSafe.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    .
    .
    .
```

I am using this SpringBootApplication header:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
        WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

Can anyone help me with that ? I am running 2.0.1.RELEASE spring boot version. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently Spring Boot Micrometer [requires `net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.10.4`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/build.gradle). You are using a different Ehcache version in your code, one that doesn't have `net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache.getStatistics()` method.

Use Ehcache 2.10.4 or newer if you plan to use Spring Boot Micrometer.